# Yes/No Is $\mathbb{Z}_3$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6? $

Tags: group-theory

Is $\mathbb{Z}_3$  a  subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6? $

My attempt : I think  yes

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_3.$
Take  $a=2$ and $b= 1$ then $a + (-b)=2-1 = 1 \in \mathbb{Z_3}$

By subgroup criterion ,$\mathbb{Z}_3$ is  a  subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$

Comment: This is hard to follow.  $2+1=3$ which is not in your supposed subgroup.

Comment: @lulu  $1$ inverse is $-1$

Comment: Note that all $\mathbb Z_3$ is, is a cyclic group of order $3$.  Accordingly, can you find an element of order $3$ in $\mathbb Z_6$?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean exactly by $\mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z_6$. You could ask if the former is isomorphic to a subgroup of the latter, and then it would make more sense...

Comment: So what?  Your supposed subgroup consists of $\{0,1,2\}$, yes?  But that's not closed under addition.

Comment: @lulu Im unable to find an element of order $3$ in $\mathbb{Z_6}$

Comment: Then you did not look very hard. What's the order of $1$?  What's the order of $2$?  What's the order of $3$? ...  Remember, you are speaking of the additive group here.  $\mathbb Z_n$ is not a group under multiplication.

Comment: @lulu Here elements of $\mathbb{Z_6}$  are  $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}. 1^1=1, 2^3=8=2 , 3^3=27=3,4^3=64=4,5^3=125=5$

Comment: Please think about what you are doing.  As I mentioned, your question concerns the *additive* group.  $1$, for instance has order $6$ since $6\times 1 =1+1+1+1+1+1=0$ and no smaller multiple of $1$ yields $0$.  Now try $2$.

Comment: okay @lulu let me think about it

Comment: @lulu You mean $1+1+1=3,2+2+2=6=0,3+3+3=9=3,4+4+4=0,5+5+5=15=3$.          
                       No element of order $3$ in $\mathbb{Z_6}$.But we can find  a subgroup $H=\{0,2,4\}$ of order $3$

Comment: Im sorry for a misunderstanding  @lulu $2+2+2=0$  . $2$ is an element of order $3 $ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$. I thought that $1$ is the Identity of $\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists subgroup of $\mathbb Z_6$ which is isomorphic with $\mathbb Z_3$, but $\mathbb Z_3$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_6$.

Because $\mathbb Z_3=\{a+3\mathbb Z\mid a\in\mathbb Z\}$, $\mathbb Z_6=\{a+6\mathbb Z\mid a\in\mathbb Z\}$, so $\mathbb Z_3$ is not subset of $\mathbb Z_6$.